# I'm trying to design an algorithm which finds the starting letter of each given word and then saves it into an array kinda like a histogram

Tags: c

First of all, I only recently started to learn to code so it might be something pretty obvious that I'm missing. I'm sorry if that's the case.

When given the words, the algorithm always skips the first word and starts from the second one. I tried analyzing it by hand but couldn't figure out the problem. I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i;
    char word[100][100];
    char tmp;
    int counter[100];

    printf("Enter the number of words ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the word ");
        scanf("%s", word[i]);
    }

    for(i='a'; i<'z'; i++)
    {
        counter[i]=0;
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        tmp=word[i][0];
        counter[tmp]=counter[tmp]+1;
    }

    for(i='a'; i<'z'; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", counter[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, maybe you first word starts with an uppercase letter. You only consider lowercase letters in your code!

Comment: No reason for `counter` to have `100` elements, right?  Maybe `26` or `2 * 26`.

Comment: You have buffer overflow when zero'ing the `counter` array. e.g. `'z'` value (in ASCII) is 122 whereas the array can hold only 100 elements. That zero'ing loop can be omitted if you initialize it with `int counter[100] = {0};`.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell why the first word is not being counted without seeing the input you are passing to the program, but the 2 issues I see here are:

1. You are treating the ASCII values of each character as the index. In ASCII, 'A' has a value of 65, 'Z' is 90, 'a' is 97, 'z' is 122. your counter array only goes up to 100, so trying to access counter['z'] will go out of the array bounds and will corrupt memory on the stack and cause unexpected results. Since we are only considering letters and not all ASCII characters, we should make our array sized 26, and we should access it by converting each ASCII char to an index. This can be done by subtracting 'a' (thus 'a'-'a' will yield an index of 0, 'b'-'a' will yield an index of 1, etc.)
2. You are not considering uppercase letters. These are a different range of ASCII values from lowercase letters, and it is a good idea to convert all letter to lowercase before indexing into our array.

Here is a version of the code with these two changes:

```
int main()
{
    int n,i;
    char word[100][100];
    char tmp;
    const int numLetters = 'z' - 'a' + 1;
    int counter[numLetters];

    printf("Enter the number of words ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the word ");
        scanf("%s", word[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; i<numLetters; i++)
    {
        counter[i]=0;
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        tmp=word[i][0];
        //convert the letter to lowercase
        tmp=tolower(tmp);
        
        //subtract tmp-'a' to get the array index
        counter[tmp-'a']++;
    }

    for(i=0; i<numLetters; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", counter[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are indexing the array `counter[]` with character code values `'a'`(97) to `'z'`(122), but the array length is 100.  You are overrunning the buffer, and stomping on adjacent variables - in this case the start of `word[0]`, and probably `tmp`, but that is uninitialised at that point so has no impact.

What is actually adjacent to a particular variable is undefined and will depend on how the compiler locates and orders data objects in memory; in a different compiler you may well have different results, including simply crashing and aborting.

The initialisation loop is unnecessary; you can zero the entire array thus:

```
int counter[100] = {0} ;
```

There are other issues of code safety and style, but *semantic* errors include your loops stopping one short of `'z'`.  To include `'z'` you need `<= 'z'` or `< 'z'+1`:

```
for( int i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++ )
{
    printf("%d", counter[i]);
}
```

Allocating more than 26 elements `counter` array is unnecessary.  Better to calculate the range from the character values:

```
int counter['z'-'a' + 1] = {0} ;
```

You should then generate the index by subtracting `'a'` from the character code value:

```
for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    char index = word[i][0] - 'a' ;
    counter[index]++ ;
}
```

To treat upper and lower case the same you might want to ignore case:

```
char index = tolower(word[i][0]) - 'a' ;
```

Your output will make no sense if any letter has a count > 10.  You need to delimit each value with space or comma for example.

```
for( int i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++ )
{
    printf("%-3d", counter[i]);
}
```

You can add clarity by defining a constant for the number of characters:

```
#define NUM_COUNTERS ('z'-'a' + 1)
```

simplifying the `counter[]` declaration and the output loop:

```
int counter[NUM_COUNTERS] = {0} ;

...

for( int i = 0; i < NUM_COUNTERS; i++ )
{
    printf( "%-3d ", counter[i - 'a'] ) ;
}
```

To prevent overrunning `words[]` you should limit the value if `n` and further prevent entering more than 99 characters per word.

All together:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_WORDS 100
#define NUM_COUNTERS ('z'-'a' + 1)

int main()
{
    int n = 0 ;
    printf( "Enter the number of words " ) ;
    scanf( "%d", &n ) ;
    if( n > MAX_WORDS )
    {
        n = MAX_WORDS ;
    }

    char word[MAX_WORDS][100] ;
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "Enter the word: " );
        scanf( "%99s", word[i] ) ;
    }

    int counter[NUM_COUNTERS] = {0} ;
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        char index = word[i][0] - 'a' ;
        counter[index]++ ;
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < NUM_COUNTERS; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%-3d ", counter[i - 'a'] ) ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```